# Google maps check if current bounds are inside the bounds of a data layer

Tags: google-maps, geojson

I am loading a data layer in a google map, over a certain country (it's a drawing over a country):

```
map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonObject);
```

I am pretty sure there isn't, but... i**s there a way to check that the bounds of the map are inside the bounds of the data layer**?

(basically, I want to know, when the user navigates on the map, if the current viewport is inside data layer);

```
var bounds = this.map.getBounds();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
```

Maybe I can query the data layer in the position of the south west bound and check for some props. indicating that I am inside that data layer?

**Or at least:**

Does anyone know a way how to get a certain feature object programmatically, knowing the lat and long?

Here the google maps uses events to get to the feature object:

```
 map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    event.feature.setProperty('isColorful', true);
  });
```

But I do not want to use events. **Is there a method to supply the coordinates of a point and get to the feature object?**
Something like:

```
map.getFeature(lat, long).setProperty('isColorful', true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`google.maps.LatLngBounds.contains` function could be utilized for that purpose, but since it accepts a single location, the following solution is suggested:

1) initialize data layer bounds from GeoJSON coordinates:

```
var dataLayer = map.data;
var layerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
//1.collect all coordinates from data layer
dataLayer.forEach(function(f) {
    var geometry = f.getGeometry();
    processCoordinates(geometry, layerBounds.extend, layerBounds);
});
```

2) determine whether map bounds are within a layer bounds:

```
if (layerBounds.contains(map.getBounds().getNorthEast()) && layerBounds.contains(map.getBounds().getSouthWest())) {
  //...   
}
```

**Working example**

> In the provided example *green colored* area will be displayed if map 
>   bounds are within a layer bounds, and the *red colored* in
>   the opposite case:

```js
var area;
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 53.349248,
            lng: -6.255323
        },
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    displayDataLayer(map);

    document.getElementById("btnShow").onclick = function() {
        var result = displayDataLayerBoundsArea(map);
    };
}


function displayDataLayer(map) {
    var dataLayer = map.data;
    dataLayer.loadGeoJson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/440708612b574764c309/raw/2a4e2feadc204806440c51a14c2ef1f54f4fc3d8/Census2011_Province_generalised20m.json');
    dataLayer.setMap(map);
}

function displayDataLayerBoundsArea(map) {
    var dataLayer = map.data;
    var layerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    //1.collect all coordinates from data layer
    dataLayer.forEach(function(f) {
        var geometry = f.getGeometry();
        processCoordinates(geometry, layerBounds.extend, layerBounds);
    });

    if (area != null) {
        area.setMap(null);
    }

    //2.determine whether map bounds are contained within a layer bounds
    if (layerBounds.contains(map.getBounds().getNorthEast()) && layerBounds.contains(map.getBounds().getSouthWest())) {
        //map.fitBounds(bounds);
        area = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: '#00FF00',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            bounds: {
                north: layerBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                south: layerBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
                east: layerBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                west: layerBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
            }
        });
    } else {
        //map.fitBounds(bounds);
        area = new google.maps.Rectangle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            bounds: {
                north: layerBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
                south: layerBounds.getSouthWest().lat(),
                east: layerBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
                west: layerBounds.getSouthWest().lng()
            }
        });
    }
}


function processCoordinates(geometry, callback, thisArg) {
    if (geometry instanceof google.maps.LatLng) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry);
    } else if (geometry instanceof google.maps.Data.Point) {
        callback.call(thisArg, geometry.get());
    } else {
        geometry.getArray().forEach(function(g) {
            processCoordinates(g, callback, thisArg);
        });
    }
}
```

```css
#map {
   width: 800px;
   height: 640px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnShow">Show</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/otcnLyou/)